# Coprime matching of an integer's d(n) divisors with the set of the first d(n) integers

Tags: nt.number-theory

A positive integer *n* is said to be *matchable* if there is a coprime matching of its d(*n*) divisors with the set of the first d(*n*) positive integers, that is a bijection from one set to the other in which corresponding numbers are coprime. Thus, while 36 is not matchable, 54 is because its 8 divisors can be coprime matched with the set of the integers 1 to 8 as follows: {(1,6),(2,3),(3,8),(6,7),(9,4),(18,5),(27,2),(54,1)}.

**Are matchable integers more numerous than integers that are not?**

Comment: I presume that the question should be interpreted as "Is the natural density of the matchable integers greater than $\tfrac12$?" Certainly there is a countable infinity of non-matchable integers, and the density of matchable numbers is bounded above by $\tfrac34$, because no multiple of $4$ is matchable.

Comment: @PeterTaylor: 4 itself is matchable: (1,2), (2,1), (3,4)

Comment: Odd unmatchable numbers start with 243, 405, 567, 675, 729, 891, 945, 1053, 1215, 1323, 1377, 1485, 1539, 1701, 1755, 1863, ...

Comment: Here is a [sample Sage code](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJxdj8EKgzAMhu-C75DLoAUnCjsNvHjZQ8iQalsNm2lJ455_Og8byykQ_u__gksMLIDiWEJ4pjzLM-s8YOoXI-NshqdTpK95Btu00ECL0bBsgRubOKtOnW3x0OADw7YA0hdWRg52HUVZfGEKnDZSoeqypHUZHPfB9z8XrQE9TKNVO7Bp6rs-WtnJygRtOZvUR8fejXLYIU1K78odfQRor98L6qqqPjg6XcCQBQry_9P9DZsvULc=&lang=sage&interacts=eJyLjgUAARUAuQ==) that checks matchability and lists all unmatchable numbers that are not multiples of 4 below 1000.

Comment: Have these sequences been submitted to oeis.org?

Comment: It seems from the code that divisors of matchable numbers are matchable. Is this clear (or even true)? If so, it would come in rather handy, since via a nice inductive argument, the number $2\cdot 3^2\cdot 5^4\cdots p_N^{p_N-1}$ is matchable (making use of the fact that the $d(n)$ of such a number is just its radical). Then, if the above were true, in particular all cubefree numbers not divisible by $4$ would be matchable, and those are already a proportion of $\frac{6}{7\zeta(3)}\approx 0.713$ of all numbers.

Comment: My conjecture: $n$ is matchable if and only if $$\tau\big(\frac{n}d\big) \leq \left\lceil \frac{(d-1)\tau(n)}d\right\rceil$$
for every divisor $d>1$ of $\mathrm{rad}(n)$. This condition is surely necessary, and I believe it's also sufficient (verified numerically for $n\leq 10^5$).This would further imply that any divisor of $2\cdot 3^2\cdots p_N^{p_N-1}$ is matchable and prove @JoachimKönig's assertion.

Comment: Note that if the inequality given by @Max is true for all prime divisors $d$ of (the radical of) $n$, then it holds for all divisors $d>1$ of the radical of $n$; if you replace $d$ by any multiple of $d$, the left side decreases while the right side increases. So it suffices to check the condition for all prime divisors $d$ of $n$.